# Iterate through a list up to a percentage of its length - Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am working on a loop that intends to read 90% of the values in a one-dimensional array/list, and then store this in a new list.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Provide your attempt and some sample input and desired output

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `new_lst` you will have 90% values of `original_lst`:

```
original_lst = list(range(10))

new_lst = original_lst[:int(len(original_lst)*0.9)]
print(new_lst)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: you don't need to cast it to a list before indexing or finding the `len` you can do that afterwards as it might be more efficient to the outcome of the problem

Comment: @aws_apprentice Do you mean the `range()`? I just did it as an example of quick list creation. Of course, in real world you don't this usually.

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate the length of the list ~~> X.
2. Calculate 90% of X ~~> Y (round in the direction you want).
3. Grab the first Y elements, for example (iterate from i=0 to i=Y-1).

This is actually the mechanism behind python list comprehension.